# Is this correct implementation of my initialize List function for a Linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Everywhere I look about Linked List implementation, I see that when I initialize a list my code should look something like this:

```
typedef struct node {
int val;
struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

But my assignment says this for my initialize function: Write a function initializeList  which creates a linked list of employee information where each node contains an employeeData struct and a pointer called next.

What I got from that is to do this, but I dont think its right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

FILE * data;

typedef struct{              // Main struct containing needed data types
    int EMP_ID;
    int dep;
    int rank;
    double salary;
    char name[20];
    } node;

struct node { node employeeData; struct node *next; };    // struct node
struct node *head, *z, *t;

initializeList ( node employeeData, FILE *data ) // initialize list function
{

    head = ( node * ) malloc( sizeof *head );
    z = ( node * ) malloc( sizeof *z );
    head->next = z;
    z->next = z;
}

int main (void)
{
    data = fopen( "empInfo.txt","r" );
    node employeeData = {0,0,0,0,0};



    while (getchar () != '\n')
    getchar ();

    fclose( data );
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a correct implementation of this? Very new to programming so please be easy on me. My assignment is no where near done so I am aware that it doesn't really do anything right now.

Comment: You have 2 structs called `node`, you should rename one.

Comment: `head = ( node * ) malloc( sizeof *head );` : `(node *)` should be `(struct node *)` or omit. Also Your code does nothing throughout.

Comment: Your `initializeList()` should have an explicit return type of `void` and needs to take a pointer to a `node`, not a copy of a `node`.  You can't get information/changes back to the calling code otherwise.  It doesn't use the `data` parameter.  It does trample the `head` global variable each time it is called, which is unlikely to lead to happiness.

Comment: Thanks guys! How do I accept one of these as an answer?

Comment: You don't have an answer yet.